# Independent variables of infinite mean

Tags: probability

> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ are iid with $E[|X_i|] = \infty$. Let $S_n = X_1 + \dotsb + X_n$, and let $A$ be the event that $M_n = S_n/n$ converges to a finite limit. Let $B$ be the event that $|X_n| \geq n$ infinitely often.
>
> 1. State the definition of $B$ in terms of unions and intersections.
> 2. Show that $P(B) = 1$.
> 3. Verify the identity $M_n − M_{n+1} = \frac{M_n}{n+1} − \frac{X_{n+1}}{n + 1}$ and use it to show that $A ∩ B = \emptyset$.
> 4. Use the above to prove that $P(A) = 0$.

Mean is infinite so SLLN can't be used here, what kind of theory can be applied in this kind of problem in probability?

Use Borel Cantlli, if we let $A_n = \{\omega: \lvert X_n(\omega) \geq n\}$, and prove $\sum P[A_n] = \infty$ then it is done but I can't do that.

Comment: Borell Cantelli lemma

Comment: @Mason Thanks, but how do I make use of the condition that $E[\lvert X_i \rvert] = \infty$ to use Borell Cantelli?

Comment: Maybe $E(|X_1|) = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(|X_1| \geq x)\,dx$ will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We follow the argument in Exercise 4.6 in David Williams' book "Probability with martingales".

Let $k > 0$ be an arbitrarily large number.
Consider $|X_n| > kn$, instead of $|X_n| > n$.

Since $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ are identically distributed,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n| \ge kn) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_1| \ge kn). $$
By applying Fubini's theorem, it holds that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_1| \ge kn) = E\left[ \sum_{n \ge 1} {\bf 1}_{\{|X_1|/k \ge n\}} \right] = E\left[\lfloor \frac{|X_1|}{k} \rfloor\right] = +\infty,$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the integer part of a real number $x$.
Now by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we see that $P$-a.s.,$|X_n| > kn$ infinitely many $n$.
By this and the triangle inequality, it holds that $P$-a.s.,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| +  \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n-1}\right| \ge k.  $$

We can show that
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n-1}\right| = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|. $$

Hence, it holds that $P$-a.s.,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| \ge \frac{k}{2}.$$

By recalling that $k$ is taken arbitrarily,
it holds that $P$-a.s.,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| = +\infty.$$

---

1. $ B = \cap_{N \ge 1} \cup_{n \ge N} \{|X_n| \ge n\}$.
2. Let $k=1$ in the above argument.
3. On the event $A$,
   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} M_{n+1} - M_{n} + \frac{M_{n}}{n+1} = 0$$ and hence, $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
4. This follows from 2 and 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "Consider $|X_n| > kn$, instead of $|X_n| > kn$. " Also, if we let $k=1$, then this answer my question (b)? right?

Comment: I corrected a typo. If we let $k=1$, then this answers (b).